# how to sort multi dimensional arrays in php based on inner values

Tags: arrays, sorting

I have this array result and want to sort based on name

```
$arr = array
(0 => array
        (
            (name) => Medianas empresas
            (count) => 17
            [applied] => 
            [url] => /es/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&Itemid=230&usage=Medianas+empresas
        )

    1 => array
        (
            [name] => Grandes empresas y gobierno
            [count] => 8
            [applied] => 
            [url] => /es/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&Itemid=230&usage=Grandes+empresas+y+gobierno
        )

    2 => array
        (
            [name] => Microempresas
            [count] => 9
            [applied] => 
            [url] => /es/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&Itemid=230&usage=Microempresas
        )

)
```

The result should be like,

```
$arr = array
(
       1 => array
        (
            [name] => Grandes empresas y gobierno
            [count] => 8
            [applied] => 
            [url] => /es/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&Itemid=230&usage=Grandes+empresas+y+gobierno
        )
       0 => array
        (
            (name) => Medianas empresas
            (count) => 17
            [applied] => 
            [url] => /es/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&Itemid=230&usage=Medianas+empresas
        )
    2 => array
        (
            [name] => Microempresas
            [count] => 9
            [applied] => 
            [url] => /es/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&Itemid=230&usage=Microempresas
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you try anything? What is not working?

Comment: The sorting has to be made based on name value of inner array. Tried array_multisort. But the error is scalar values not allowed.

Comment: Thank u all for your support. got the answer. :)

Comment: foreach ($cf['filters'] as $key => $row) {
$filter_array[$key] = $row[0];
}

array_multisort($filter_array, SORT_DESC, $cf['filters']);

Answer (score 0):

The desired result is in fact identical to the one you have, so, there is nothing to do.

If you confounded indices 0 and 1 in your desired result, just

```
sort($arr);
```

would do the job.

Comment: If u see the second array, the sorting was made based on inner array name value. I just want to sort name parameter.